# Excel Ribbon adding own tabs

Tags: excel, ribbon

Adding ribbon controls seems strightforward enough, but how do I make it so that the extra tab I have only apears when I open a specific workbook.

I want it so that who ever opens the workbook will get the tabs, these tabs and buttons fire of the macros with in this one work book.

do you have to code this dynamicaly or is it possible to tie ribbon customiations to workbooks?

Comment: This link explains how to add a custom ribbon tab to a specific Excel file: http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm   Other options are available: in Excel 2010 I think you can dynamically add items to the ribbon using VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addition to the link tim provided (which explains in pretty good detail).

If you are more interested in getting somthing simple working, this [handy tool](http://www.datapigtechnologies.com/Custom_UI_Builder.zip) will help build custom menus.